# scss loader doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, sass

When I try to include my `.scss` files to template it doesn't work. Like they wouldn't exists at all. my app structure:

```
- src
  - components
        - App.vue
        - Login.vue
  - js
        - app.js
  - scss
        - app.scss
        - bootstrap-custom.scss
        - main.scss
```

everything on vue app seems working properly but not styles. so in my `App.vue` I import those like this

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import '../scss/app.scss';
</style>
```

and so on my `scss/app.scss`

```
@import 'bootstrap-custom.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'main.scss';
```

and my webpack config

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
             options: {
                 loaders: {
                     'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                     'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                 }
             }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(css|less|scss)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

so it seems i do everything good but still can't see the result?

Comment: have you installed sass-loader and node-sass ?

Comment: yes and it is working. as I can see now it loads bootstrap but not my custom files.

Comment: ok so its reversed, it loads my custom files but not bootstrap from node modules. have no idea why. also once it loads custom css it mounts it on `body[data-v-7cd7112a]` for example but as I can see this data attribute starts appending only on #app container. how come?

Comment: @ArnasPecelis The data attribute is related to [scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html)